# Partition keys using nodejs, mongoose and azure cosmos db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

After creating a new partitioned collection on Azure Cosmos DB with a shard key, I want to insert and recover data from it using nodejs via mongoose database adapter.

Let's say my partitioned collection is *action* with shard key *actionId*. How should I proceed? It is need to use the *partitionKey* key or *enableCrossPartitionQuery* key on the mongoose queries to attack to the right shard?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const actionModel = new mongoose.Schema({
    actionId: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
 }, {
    shardKey: { actionId: 1 },
 });

actionModel.create({ actionId, name}, (err, response) => {
    //logic
});

actionModel.findOne({ actionId }, (err, response) => {
    //logic
});

actionModel.findOneAndUpdate({ actionId }, data, { new: true, lean: true }, (err, response) => {
    //logic
});
```

According Mongoose documentation, no need to do anything more. But what if I want to do an update via another field?

> Each sharded collection is given a shard key which must be present in
>   all insert/update operations. We just need to set this schema option
>   to the same shard key and we’ll be all set.

Comment: Is there any approach that you were able to find?